# How to make a repeat move in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, move

I'm using JavaScript to make a progres bar when downloading files. I have done it to move from server to client as a picture, but I don't know how to make it to repeat so the progress will continue. I have used this script. What do I have to do?

```
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:142px;
    height:140px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(server.png);
}
#apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:142px;
    height:140px;
    z-index:2;
    left: 500px;
    top: 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(laptop.png);
}
#apDiv3 {
    position:absolute;
    width:346px;
    height:140px;
    z-index:3;
    left: 153px;
    top: 15px;
}
body {
}
</style>
<div id="apDiv1"></div>
<div id="apDiv2"></div>
<div id="apDiv3"><br />
  <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var imgObj = null;
var animate ;
function init(){
   imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
   imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
   imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
}
function moveRight(){
imgObj.style.left = 200 + 200 + 'px';
if (10 <= left) {
imgObj.style.left = (left + 300) + 'px';
imgObj.style.visibility='visible';

} else

if (left>=500) {
imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}
}
function animate(){
animate = setTimeout(moveRight,200);

}
window.onload =init;
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<img src="file:///C|/Documents and Settings/Administrator/Desktop/New Folder (2)/folder.png" width="65" height="67" id="myImage" />
<p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
<input type="button" value="Shkarko" onclick="moveRight();" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the `left` variable you're using? It's not declared or set anywhere...

Comment: Need the HTML that goes with it.  Can you JSFiddle it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`:

```
function animate(){
    animateInterval = setInterval(moveRight,200);
}
```

When you are ready for it to stop animating, call `clearInterval(animateInterval)`

Make sure to rename your `animate` variable so that it does not conflict with the `animate()` function.  You'll also need to actually call `animate()` at some point to get it started.

**Edit:**  You need to crack open your JavaScript console and look at the error messages you get (hint: hit the <kbd>f12</kbd> key).  You get an error on the second statement of `moveRight()` because `left` is not defined.

Also, `animate()` is never called, so any interval or timeout you set up would never be triggered.

There is a logic error in `moveRight()`.  Even if `left` were defined, your `else if` statement would never be called.  If `left` *is* greater than `500`, it is *also* greater than `10`.  The first `if` will be called and the `else if` will thus be ignored.

Your HTML is invalid.  You have a close `</head>` tag with no matching open `<head>` tag. And you have an open `<body>` tag without a closing `</body>` tag.  If you *did* have those tags, you'd be in other trouble - the `<div>` elements would be in the `<head>`, and thus wouldn't even be rendered. The last `<div>` element's closing tag would appear in the `<body>` even though the open tag is in the `<head>`.

Comment: @Arsi - I can't see how it would've moved even once before.  Your code logic seems kind of wonky.  Maybe you didn't post all of it.

Comment: i have update the code source, i have copy all the html that i have written, it work when i click the button

Comment: What can i do?
How can i write e java script to make a progres download, i want it for a project in school. i dont know what to do more.

Comment: @Arsi - It looks like you need to go back to the basics before you start trying to do JavaScript.  Maybe start with Google's [beginner tutorial videos](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/).

Comment: Look i have done this till now:
[Project](http://arsidj.com/project/project.html)
[Project 1](http://arsidj.com/project/project1.html)

Comment: @Arsi - You have html mixed in with your JavaScript.  Remove the `<br/>` tags inside your `moveRight()` function.